# Linq selecting from GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select every group into custom class and every item into another custom class,

I done this like this:

```
_notificationsManager
    .GetUserNotifications(_repositoryNotifications, _memberShipProvider)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .Select(g => new NotificationsGroupData {
          Name = g.Key,
          Notifications = g.Take(3).Select(s => new NotificationData  {
                                           Category = g.Key,
                                           Text = s.Text,
                                           Time = DateTime.Now.Subtract(s.Time)
                                         })
     })
```

Here the NotificationsGroupData:

```
public class NotificationsGroupData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<NotificationData> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

And NotificationData:

```
public class NotificationData
{
    public virtual TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public virtual string Category { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

But when I'm trying to create loop over this I'm getting error:
The method or operation is not implemented.

On this line:

```
@foreach (var group in Model.Notifications)
```

How I can fix it?

**Uodate:**
I updated the code to this:

```
_notificationsManager.GetUserNotifications(_repositoryNotifications, _memberShipProvider)
                                             .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                                             .Select(g => new
                                                 {
                                                     Name = g.Key,
                                                     Notifications =
                                                              g.OrderBy(o => o.Time)
                                                               .Take(3)
                                                               .Select(s => new
                                                                   {
                                                                       Category = g.Key,
                                                                       s.Text,
                                                                       s.Time
                                                                   })
                                                 }).AsEnumerable().Select(g => new NotificationsGroupData
                                                     {
                                                         Name = g.Name,
                                                         Notifications = g.Notifications
                                                                          .Select(s => new NotificationData
                                                                              {
                                                                                  Category = g.Name,
                                                                                  Text = s.Text,
                                                                                  Time = now - s.Time
                                                                              })
                                                     })
```

And here the error:

```
The method or operation is not implemented.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

Source Error: @foreach (var group in Model.Notifications)

Stack Trace: 


[NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.] NHibernate.Linq.GroupBy.NonAggregatingGroupByRewriter.FlattenSubQuery(SubQueryExpression subQueryExpression, QueryModel queryModel) +608    NHibernate.Linq.GroupBy.NonAggregatingGroupByRewriter.ReWrite(QueryModel queryModel) +598    NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root) +126    NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) +208    NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +51    NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +100    NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +74    NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +53  NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters) +320   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow) +188    NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression) +164    NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery) +152    NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
+70    NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +59    Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator() +128  System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +61    ASP._Page_Views_Layout_Notifications_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Dev\Projects\ADDE\ADDE\Views\Layout\Notifications.cshtml:21    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +103    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +88    System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235    System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107    System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
+291    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
+23    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
+22    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
+75    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
+50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
+31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9() +22    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3() +10    System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +27   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action) +64 System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +71    System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1464

[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.] System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +3033503    System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +76    System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +28    System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +19    System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +463    System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName) +35    ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Dev\Projects\ADDE\ADDE\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:33    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +103    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +88    System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +233    System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +71    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +64    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +246    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95    System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235    System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107    System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
+291    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
+23    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
+22    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
+75    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
+50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
+31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
+9629708    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Whats the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Is it Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities?

Comment: This is the error that I'm getting: "Argument types do not match", It Linq ti Entities

Comment: @RafaelZilberman which argument types not match? I believe you have that info

Comment: which error do you get, the `NotImplementedException` or the `ArgumentException`?

Comment: What type you have as a return type in method GetUserNotifications(_repositoryNotifications, _memberShipProvider)? I guess it is IQueryable, right? My bet that 
`DateTime.Now.Subtract(s.Time)` is a root cause of this issue.

Comment: @user287107 "ArgumentException: Argument types do not match", "System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Bind(MemberInfo member, Expression expression)"

Comment: @outcoldman IQueryable<Notification>

Comment: My mistake the error I getting is "System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented."

Comment: then you can see in the stacktrace, which method has not been programmed yet.

Comment: @RafaelZilberman why are you doing this calculation `Time = DateTime.Now.Subtract(s.Time)`? Why not simply assign `Time = s.Time` ?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I changed it to `Time = s.Time` and still getting error

Comment: @RafaelZilberman that's very strange. `Time = s.Time` should work. Looks like problem is not in Linq query

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Maybe the error is in NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem may well be in the `DateTime.Now.Subtract(s.Time)` part, possibly combined with your use of `NotificationsGroupData`.

I suggest you change your query to simply fetch all the data you need without processing it much, and then perform the more complex work locally using `AsEnumerable`. So something like:

```
// Use a single common idea of "now", don't re-evaluate each time
var now = DateTime.Now;
var query = _notificationsManager
    .GetUserNotifications(_repositoryNotifications, _memberShipProvider)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .Select(g => new {
      Name = g.Key,
      Notifications = g.Take(3)
                       .Select(s => new {
                           Text = s.Text,
                           Time = s.Time
                       })
    })
    .AsEnumerable() // Force local evaluation for final step
    .Select(g => new NotificationsGroupData {
      Name = g.Name,
      Notifications = g.Notifications
                       .Select(s => new NotificationData {
                           Category = g.Name,
                           Text = s.Text,
                           Time = now - s.Time
                       })
    });
```

EDIT: Okay, as that's still giving problems, you could try doing *everything* post-grouping in-process:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var query = _notificationsManager
    .GetUserNotifications(_repositoryNotifications, _memberShipProvider)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .AsEnumerable() // Force local evaluation for final step
    .Select(g => new NotificationsGroupData {
      Name = g.Key,
      Notifications = g.Take(3)
                       .Select(s => new NotificationData {
                           Category = g.Key,
                           Text = s.Text,
                           Time = now - s.Time
                       })
    });
```

Note that this is far from idea - it'll pull all the properties from the database, not just the ones you want. (And not just the first three - although "first" depends on the ordering too, which hasn't been specified anywhere that we can see.) It could be that this is one of those situations where you need to fall back to SQL, but it does sound like NHibernate could be doing more for you...

Comment: @RafaelZilberman: You should give more information. Please edit the complete error into your question - ideally the original error, and the error after using my code.

Comment: @RafaelZilberman: Hmm. I'm wondering whether the `Take` is the problem. Could you try removing that temporarily (but sticking with the rest of my code), just to see if that's it?

Comment: I deleted the .Take and still getting the error, I think the problem is in NHibernate. **Update**: I found the problem, the problem is the subQuery...

Comment: @RafaelZilberman: Sounds like it. That's odd. Next step - try removing the first `Select` as well. I'll edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: I found the problem, the problem is the subQuery... But How I can fix it?

Comment: @RafaelZilberman: *Please* check the generated SQL to see how awful it is before celebrating too much. You may well want to write custom HQL or SQL instead.

Comment: @RafaelZilberman: I haven't used NHibernate for a while, but you should be able to configure logging so that you can see what SQL is executed.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate cannot translate your query to sql. The quickest solution will be to make your selection statement on inmemory collection other than pass it to NHibernate. Try this:

```
_notificationsManager
    .GetUserNotifications(_repositoryNotifications, _memberShipProvider)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .ToList()
    .Select(g => new NotificationsGroupData {
          Name = g.Key,
          Notifications = g.Take(3).Select(s => new NotificationData  {
                                           Category = g.Key,
                                           Text = s.Text,
                                           Time = DateTime.Now.Subtract(s.Time)
                                         })
     })
```

Another optin will be to write your query on HQL\SQL and pass it to NHibernate, so you'll have necessary number of data pulled from database and map it to your custom entities afterwards.